# How to launch Nomad from Tempest

Tags: ps4, mass-effect-andromeda

I'm on EOS, Site 1.

I found the Nomad, opened the crate, got it out. I was driving around, got to the Site 2. By accident went back to the tempest with the poorly placed "Return to Tempest" button. (I was trying to exit the nomad)

Relanded on EOS, but now the Nomad is aboard the Tempest and I don't know how to get it back so I can leave the shielded area of Site 1.

I searched settings > Controls, but don't see an option to launch the Nomad.

What control (PS4) do I need to launch / summon the Nomad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same thing happen to me when I first tried to get out of the Nomad.

You can call the Nomad back from any [Forward Station](http://masseffectandromeda.gamepedia.com/Forward_station). This is actually pretty convenient, since those are also the fast travel points. They also restore your life support, ammo and health, and repair the Nomad.

For more insight on the start of the game, check out Polygon's [Mass Effect: Andromeda guide: A Better Beginning walkthrough](http://www.polygon.com/mass-effect-andromeda-guide-walkthrough/2017/3/20/14938700/a-bitter-beginning-remnant-vault-forward-stations-outpost-peebee-drack-nomad)

Comment: Good advice. I still don't like the mechanic. Where I have to hike a half mile from my ship to get a vehicle from my ship. That part makes no sense whatsoever. I could accept that, if there was a panel at the foot of the ship ramp that did the same thing as a forward station. And then the choice would be mine if I walked away from the ship, or traveled in my fancy car.

Answer (score 2):

Wandering around Site 1, scanning stuff, I found the drop pod from earlier. Getting close to it, within the blue circle painted around it, I got a notice that "The Nomad was ready." I could click the pod to get the Nomad.

What a dumb system. I hope I don't need to do this often.

There's no help in this game. There should be "some" tutorial to explain this mechanism.

Comment: Yeah you don't launch the Nomad from the Tempest, you launch it from drop pods. This is because as you go out and explore further, you'll be able to call in the Nomad from further out drop pods.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that you can fast-travel to any of the drop pods (Forward Stations) using the map.  So you don't have to walk to them from the Tempest's ramp before you can spawn the Nomad..

Answer (score 0):

As per above comments, you can fast travel to forward stations and then call the Nomad. However, what if you risk going into high radiation and deplete all the shields and health? If you quickly fast travel on the map to a forward station it restores all the shield and health right? Nope, if you have damaged the life support system it won't and neither can you get extracted by the Tempest. So the best method just before you die is to pause and fast travel to the Tempest. It fully restores the Nomad and then fast travel back out to your nearest forward station again for exploration.